# asp.net page lifecycle issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0, page-lifecycle

I have a user control "header" with label to display amount of item in the basket. it does something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblBasketCount.Text = Session["basketItemsCount"]!=null?Session["basketItemsCount"].ToString():"0";
}
```

Then I have a page that has method:

```
public void btnAddItemToShoppingCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs )
{
    Session["basketItemsCount"] = (from b in db.CartItems where b.crt_ID == cartId select b).Sum(p => p.item_quantity);
}
```

The problem is that in the page life cycle addItem Method is fired after the control is already had Page_Load event. so my label will refresh only after another reload of the page.
**Edit:**
Header control is declared in Master Page:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" TagName="Footer" Src="~/Controls/Footer.ascx" %>
    <asp:Header ID="Header" runat="server" />
```

And Located in Controls folder.

I'm using WAP so its in namespace Sitename.Controls.Header

Comment: Try using Page_PreRender instead.  That event is raised right before all the controls start to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Page_Load` event (or other page events) in `UserControls`. This will lead to issues like this.
Instead you should use properties, methods and events in your control.

You could for example have a property `BasketCount` in your UserControl:

```
public String BasketCount
{
    get { lblBasketCount.Text; }
    set { lblBasketCount.Text = value; }
}
```

Then your page can use this property:

```
var basketCount = (from b in db.CartItems where b.crt_ID == cartId select b).Sum(p => p.item_quantity);
Session["basketItemsCount"] = basketCount;
MyControl.BasketCount = basketCount.ToString();
```

To get a reference to the control in your `MasterPage` you should provide a public property there that maps to it:

For example(in MasterPage):

```
public Header HeaderControl
{
     get
     {
         return Header;
     }
}
```

And you can call this property from one of your ContentPages in this way(f.e. if your master's type is named "*SiteMaster*"):

```
((SiteMaster)Page.Master).HeaderControl.BasketCount = basketCount.ToString();
```

Comment: I'm trying this and it doesn't work. 
I can't just do 
MyControl.BasketCount = basketCount.ToString(); 
as its non-static, I guess I need to do something like this: 
MyControl ctrl = (MyControl) LoadControl("MyControl.aspx");
And then it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @SergejPopov: You need the reference to your UserControl. But i'm sure that you can get it. You need to tell me where your UserControl is declared(f.e. in a container-control like GridView or in the MasterPage, etc.). Edit your question to show where it's declared.

Comment: Great that worked, with a little change: should be ((SiteMaster)Page.Master).HeaderControl.BasketCount = basketCount; Thanks a million!!!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the earlier answers, another way to accomplish what you want is to use an Update Panel for the control that shows the amount of items in the cart.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx

This way you can update it even after the page has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Session state for this.

In the user control, add a `BasketItemsCount` property.

In the `Page_Init` of the main page, set the property.

In the `Page_Load` of the user control, use the property to set the label.